# Replacing first instance of a toggling value in gvim using awk

Tags: vim, awk

I have to replace the first instance of a number in a column with some other number.
This is what I want to do

**input:**

```
54 679 75 98 21  
24 543 86 98 43  
42 543 54 98 55  
93 255 25 98 25  
43 523 43 98 31  
98 775 24 76 78  
77 564 65 76 45
```

**output:**

```
54 679 75 98 21  
24 543 86 98 43  
42 543 54 98 55  
93 255 25 98 25  
43 523 43 98 31  
98 775 24 91 78  
77 564 65 76 45
```

So that first occurrence of `76` in fourth column is replaced by `91`.
This was what I was trying to do using `awk`:

```
awk '{count=0;if ($4 == 76 && count < 1){ gsub("91","76")} count++; print}' input > output
```

But this is not helping, can anybody suggest something?

Comment: To be clear, the assignment to `count` is *inside* the braces, meaning the variable gets reset to 0 on every line. Awk knows how to do arithmetic with unset variables (default value is zero) so you can just remove `count=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(using this approach we are mentioning all the values in variables and nothing hard-coded, for any further values changes simply change the variable values and program should still work).

```
awk -v column="4" -v count="1" -v value="76" -v new_value="91" '($column == value){if(++num==count){$column=new_value}} 1' Input_file
```

Or adding a non-one liner form of solution.

```
awk -v column="4" -v count="1" -v value="76" -v new_value="91" '
($column == value){
  if(++num==count){
      $column=new_value
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
54 679 75 98 21  
24 543 86 98 43  
42 543 54 98 55  
93 255 25 98 25  
43 523 43 98 31  
98 775 24 91 78
77 564 65 76 45
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** correcting OP' attempt and adding corrections details too.

***Code should be changed to:***

```
awk '{if ($4 == 76){if(++count == 1){sub("^" 76 "$","91",$4)}};print}' Input_file
```

***Explanation of above FIX of OP's code:***

- `count=0` is a bug here since every time a new line is getting read it will make variable count's value to 0 and program will  NEVER know how many times `76` came in 4th field so I removed it.
- Now place `count<0` which actually should be `++count==1` and should be inside of BLOCK of condition `$4==76` why because eve condition is NOT TRUE(`$4==76`) variable count's value is keep increasing so let us increase then when condition `$4==76` is TRUE and then it will keep its count correctly.
- NOW I corrected `gsub` even above is FIXED still code will NOT work why because `(g)sub` pattern is `sub(current_value,replaced_value)` so you are substitution `91` with `76` which is totally opposite of your ask, and after this FIX your code should work well :)

Comment: You are 10s quicker than me lol +1 ;-) I was not sure if the value had to be exactly in the 4th column or could be anywhere! Anyway I like your answer with all the variables. Very clean

Comment: Thank you so much Ravinder. It worked.What is the error with the command i was using?

Comment: @himanshu28, please check my EDIT I have fixed your code as well as added explanation of fixed code too now.

Answer (score 4):

A little tweak to [stack0114106's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220955/5403468), to make it even more concise:

```
awk '!t && $4==76 { $4=91; t=1;} 1 ' file
```

Variables in awk that didn't assigned will have `0` or empty string value, negate it will give `true`.
And I put `!t` before the other compare equation is for efficiency, because `&&` is a shortcut operator, it will stop the second part from executing when the first part evaluates to `false`.

Last `1` is to produce a `true` there, a condition without block will have `{print $0}` block implied.

Comment: Or if we're golfing: `awk '$4==76 && !t++ {$4=91} 1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple awk

```
awk -v t=1 ' $4==76 && t==1 { $4=91; t=0;} 1 ' file
```

To correct your attempt, just wrap the initialization of count in BEGIN block and swap the match and replace inputs in gsub i.e 76 and 91

```
awk ' BEGIN {count=0; } { if ($4 == 76 && count < 1){ gsub("76","91"); count++; } print}  ' input > output
```

with your inputs

```
$ cat himanshu.txt
54 679 75 98 21
24 543 86 98 43
42 543 54 98 55
93 255 25 98 25
43 523 43 98 31
98 775 24 76 78
77 564 65 76 45

$ awk -v t=1 ' $4==76 && t==1 { $4=91; t=0;} 1 ' himanshu.txt
54 679 75 98 21
24 543 86 98 43
42 543 54 98 55
93 255 25 98 25
43 523 43 98 31
98 775 24 91 78
77 564 65 76 45

$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` command, if your `76` value can be located in any column:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i == 76 && count < 1){count++; $i=91}}print}' input
54 679 75 98 21  
24 543 86 98 43  
42 543 54 98 55  
93 255 25 98 25  
43 523 43 98 31  
98 775 24 91 78
77 564 65 76 45
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Allan .But I have to be specific to a particular column.My apologies for not mentioning in the question.

Comment: No worries! ;-) Then you don't need the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is confusing: From gvim you want to call out to awk to edit the file you're currently editing? Do it in vim:

1. jump to the top of the file: <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>
2. search for 76 in the 4th field: <kbd>/</kbd> `^[^ ]\+ [^ ]\+ [^ ]\+ 76` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. jump to the 4th field: <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>
4. change the word: <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> `91` <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
awk -v count=0 -v replace=76 -v replaceWith=91 'count==0&&$4==76{gsub("^" replace "$", replaceWith, $4); count++}1' sourceFile
```

three variables `count`, `replace` and `replaceWith` are used
`count` is to count the search term occurrence. I incremented after I found the search term `replace` and made sure I did not go back into the action again with the help of expression `count == 0`

`replace` can be any value from the list...does not have to be hardcoded.
same as with `replaceWith` that you want the value that needs to be replaced with

The result

```
awk -v count=0 -v replace=76 -v replaceWith=91  'count==0&&$4==76{sub("^" replace "$", replaceWith, $4); count++}1' sourceFile
54 679 75 98 21
24 543 86 98 43
42 543 54 98 55
93 255 25 98 25
43 523 43 98 31
98 775 24 91 78
77 564 65 76 45
```

changed the script after below feedback. replaced `gsub` with `$4 = replaceWith`

```
awk -v count=0 -v replace=76 -v replaceWith=91 'count==0 && $4==replace{$4 = replaceWith; count++}1' sourceFile
54 679 75 98 21
24 543 86 98 43
42 543 54 98 55
93 255 25 98 25
43 523 43 98 31
98 775 24 91 78
77 564 65 76 45
```